# Does Postgres database support differential backups

Tags: postgresql

Does Postgres database support differential backups

Comment: This should really be on Serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the "snapshot and archive log" way in postgresql 8.4.
See section 24.3 in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/backup.html

You have to take off the database on the initial backup.

Answer (score 0):

Something recently mentioned on the pg-admin list - ["pg-rman (PostgreSQL Recovery Manager)"](http://code.google.com/p/pg-rman/).

Answer (score 0):

pg_rman is also a tool. However this tool is not available for Windows. Suggested is to use pg_dump/pg_dumpall or Filesystem Backup. For more information, please follow the link given below:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/backup.html

Regards,
Vibhor Kumar.